# System.Data.SQLite.dll - System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, sqlite

I use SQLite and works fine on the developer machine (or machine with Visual Studio).

But it does not work on PCs without VS. I "installed" the SQLite manually (32 bit version, added to the references, Copy Local: True). I get "System.IO.FileNotFoundException" System.Data.SQLite.dll exception.

The System.Data.SQLite.dll is in the output folder.

But I can not get it to work only if I install the SQLite with this: https://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.105.2/sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.105.2.exe

Dev PC: x64 Win 10, application: x86 only

Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: Can you show us more details about the `FileNotFoundException`?

Answer (score 0):

Check which dependencies has your executable file (and, maybe, System.Data.SQLite.dll) with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) or similar program. Then put these libraries you found into executable's folder one by one, until your executable will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the 64 bit C++ runtime DLLs are getting installed.  They'll often be on the developer's system but not as often installed by your installer on the target system.  Even though this is a .NET assembly, it appears to have C++ underpinnings.